# SVN explorer for linux

Tags: linux, svn

I'm looking for GUI explorer for Linux. Like Kafana: http://kafana.org/SvnExplorer/

CLI is fine but I would like to know if there is something GUI for as :)

regards

Comment: Oh, btw, maybe better suited for SU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might like [kdesvn](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/screenshots)

Answer (score 5):

Try [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/), it supports Subversion as well as other SCM tools. (It was formerly "Nautilus SVN").

Comment: It's really buggy :(
at least with ubuntu from getdeb

Comment: Ohhh, they added (finnaly) to PPA. Will try it !
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's also [RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/).

Comment: I don't know why i didn't use this before :)
10x

Comment: Rapid is pretty good, we've been using it for some time.  The only problem with it is that it is far far far from being rapid!  It's terribly slow on our (admittedly quite large) code base.

Answer (score 3):

[SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) is great and it's multiplatform as well.